# How is $\frac{\cot10^\circ-\cot20^\circ}{\tan40^\circ(\cot10^\circ+\cot20^\circ)-2}=\frac{\sqrt3}{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can someone show me how $$\dfrac{\cot10^\circ-\cot20^\circ}{\tan40^\circ(\cot10^\circ+\cot20^\circ)-2}=\dfrac{\sqrt3}{3}$$

Is this an obvious simplification, as I really cannot see it. The LHS is equivalent to $$\dfrac{\frac{\cos10^\circ}{\sin10^\circ}-\frac{\cos20^\circ}{\sin20^\circ}}{\frac{\sin40^\circ}{\cos40^\circ}\left(\frac{\cos10^\circ}{\sin10^\circ}+\frac{\cos20^\circ}{\sin20^\circ}\right)-2}$$ which is $$\dfrac{\frac{1}{\sin20^\circ}}{\frac{\cos20^\circ}{\sin10^\circ\cos40^\circ}-2}$$ Is there a straight-forward simplification, or is this the approach?

Answer (score 6):

You need [factorisation and defactorisation formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) to solve the problem.

\begin{align}...&=\dfrac{\sin10^\circ \cos40^\circ}{\sin 20^\circ(\cos20^\circ-2\sin10^\circ\cos40^\circ)}\\
&=\dfrac{ \cos40^\circ}{2\cos 10^\circ(\cos20^\circ-2\sin10^\circ\cos40^\circ)}\\
&=\dfrac{ \cos40^\circ}{2\cos 10^\circ\cos20^\circ-2\sin20^\circ\cos40^\circ}\\
&=\dfrac{ \cos40^\circ}{\cos 30^\circ+\cos10^\circ-\sin60^\circ +\sin20^\circ}\\
&=\dfrac{ \cos40^\circ}{\cos10^\circ+\cos70^\circ}\\
&=\dfrac{ \cos40^\circ}{2\cos40^\circ \cos30^\circ}\\
&={1\over \sqrt{3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

Your analysis is accurate, but leads to an expression that I had trouble evaluating.

Starting from scratch:

---

$\underline{\text{Tools}}$

$\displaystyle\cot(\theta/2) = \frac{1 + \cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}.$

$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta).$

$\cos(2\theta) = 2\cos^2(\theta) - 1.$

$\displaystyle \tan(2\theta) = \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{\cos(2\theta)} = \frac{2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{2\cos^2(\theta) - 1}.$

---

$\underline{\text{Evaluation}}$

With all angles shown in this response, I have omitted the degree symbol, $~\circ.$

To simplify the evaluation, I will convert the expression into an expression involving $~\sin ~20~$ and $~\cos ~20.$

Let $~\dfrac{N}{D}~$ represent $~\displaystyle 
\dfrac{\cot ~10 - \cot ~20}{[ ~\tan40 ~(\cot ~10 + \cot ~20) ~] - 2}.$

Then,

$$N = \cot ~10 - \cot ~20 = \frac{1 + \cos ~20}{\sin ~20} - \frac{\cos ~20}{\sin ~20} = \frac{1}{\sin ~20}.$$

$\displaystyle \tan ~40 = \frac{2\sin ~20 ~\cos ~20}{2\cos^2  ~20 - 1}.$

$\displaystyle \cot ~10 + \cot ~20 = \frac{1 + \cos ~20}{\sin ~20} + \frac{\cos ~20}{\sin ~20} = \frac{1 + 2\cos ~20}{\sin ~20}.$

Then:

$$D = \frac{1}{\sin ~20} \times 
\left\{ ~\left[ ~\frac{2\sin ~20 ~\cos ~20}{2\cos^2 ~20 - 1} ~\right] ~\left[ ~1 + 2\cos ~20 ~\right]
-2\sin ~20 ~\right\}.$$

The challenge is to prove that $~\dfrac{N}{D} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}.$

To simplify my attack, I will divide both the numerator, $~N~$ and the denominator $~D~$ by $~\dfrac{1}{\sin ~20},~$ and then $~\color{red}{\text{re-interpret the problem}}~$ as needing to show that $~\dfrac{D}{N} = \sqrt{3}.$

---

So, the entire problem has been reduced to showing that

$$\left\{ ~\left[ ~\frac{2\sin ~20 ~\cos ~20}{2\cos^2 ~20 - 1} ~\right] ~\left[ ~1 + 2\cos ~20 ~\right]
-2\sin ~20 ~\right\} = \sqrt{3}. \tag1 $$

The LHS of (1) above can be re-expressed as

$$\frac{2\sin ~20}{2\cos^2 ~20 - 1} \times \left\{ ~[ ~(\cos ~20)(1 + 2\cos ~20) ~] - [ ~(2\cos^2 ~20 - 1) ~] ~\right\}$$

$$ = \frac{2\sin ~20}{2\cos^2 ~20 - 1} \times [ ~\cos ~20 + 1 ~]. \tag2 $$

---

So, the entire problem has been reduced to showing that

$$\frac{2\sin ~20}{2\cos^2 ~20 - 1} \times [ ~\cos ~20 + 1 ~] = \sqrt{3}. \tag3 $$

I am able to verify the assertion in (3) above as follows:

$$\sin ~20 = \cos ~70 = \cos(40 + 30) = (\cos ~40 ~\cos ~30) - (\sin ~40 ~\sin ~30).$$

This implies that

$$2 (\sin ~20 ~\sin ~30) = (\cos ~40 ~\cos ~30) - (\sin ~40 ~\sin ~30).$$

This implies that

$$(\sin ~30) (\sin ~40 + 2\sin ~20) = \cos ~40 ~\cos ~30.$$

This implies that

$$\frac{\sin ~40 + 2\sin ~20}{\cos ~40} = \cot ~30 = \sqrt{3}.$$

This implies that

$$\frac{(2\sin ~20 ~\cos ~20) + 2\sin ~20}{2\cos^2 ~20 - 1}  = \sqrt{3}.$$

This implies that

$$\frac{2\sin ~20}{2\cos^2 ~20 - 1} \times [ ~\cos ~20 + 1 ~] = \sqrt{3}. $$

So, equation (3) above is proven, so the problem is solved.